# Spring Boot doesn't allow Optional Bean to be Lazy when running tests

Tags: java, spring-boot

In my Spring Boot 2.1 application, I have a service class that looks something like this:

```
@Service
public class AImpl implements A {
    @Autowired
    B bservice;
}
```

And then the autowired service B looks like this:

```
@Service
public class BImpl implements B {
    @Autowired(required = false)
    @Lazy
    org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations restTemplate;
}
```

And in my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {...})
@DataJpaTest
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.xxx")
@EntityScan("com.xxx")
public class CImplTest {
    @Autowired
    B bservice;
    @Autowired
    A aservice;
}
```

When running my tests, I get the following error message:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations' available: Optional dependency not present for lazy injection point
```

However when running the application, I don't face this issue and it runs fine.

NOTE: I have tried replacing the rstTemplate Autowiring with Java 8 Optional and it doesn't work well.

Comment: How exactly do you create the `RestTemplate` bean?

Comment: I was able to run without any exception with very similar configuration. Is the exception being thrown immediately during/after test startup, or it happens when you try to access `BImpl.restTemplate` ? If you don't touch the optional bean, than there is no trouble in my local.

Comment: Don't know why but this is actually causing me a lot of problems. However, I worked around this using the `ObjectProvider` Spring provides. Leaving this here for others if any one comes across

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the exact solution to this problem but when tried with Java 8 optional type, this didn't work out. However, when I switched to Spring's `ObjectProvider`, it is working fine. Ideally, this is just a workaround and not the root cause for this issue.